# Netsuite custom field does not display data in search results

Tags: netsuite

I'm new to Netsuite, so please bear with me.  I have created a saved item search that is working fine with one exception; one of the result columns I have chosen is not displaying data in the returned rows.  This is a custom field created by our old Netsuite Administrator and it does display data on an item record, just not in search results.  I've done some searching and thought I found the problem when I read another post that said that "Global Search" and "Show In List" needed to be checked on the custom field.  I did that, but the search results still do not display any data for that column.

The field is a custom item field of the type decimal number.  Store value, show in list and global search is checked.  The field is applied to inventory items, non-inventory items, kit/package and assembly/bill of materials.  What am I missing?  TIA

Answer (score 3):

I suspect the field has field level access permissions. Go to the field definition and click the 'Access' tab. The 'Default Level or Searching/Reporting' should be at least 'Run'.

Global Search on a field makes it so if you enter a value in the Global Search bar that matches the field's value for an item then that item will be shown as a possible match. It has nothing to do with your issue. Neither does Show in List.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but my problem ended up being that the Field is Defaulted by a Saved Search.